# Verifying if a morphism is finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $X:=Z(xz-y^2)\subset\mathbb{P}^1$ and the following morphism:

\begin{align*} 
\phi:X &\to\mathbb{P}^1\\
(a:b:c) &\mapsto (a:b)\,\,\text{for } (a,b)\neq (0, 0)\\
(a:b:c) &\mapsto (b:c)\,\,\text{for } (b,c)\neq (0,0)
\end{align*}

I'm trying to check whether or not $\phi$ is a finite morphism (i.e., if $\phi^*$ is finite morphism of $k$-algebras).

My usual approach is this: every finite morphism is surjective and has finite fibers, so if any of these two properties fail for $\phi$, then $\phi$ it can't be finite.

This strategy doesn't work here, so I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Surely $\phi$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Simply write down an explicit formula how the morphism looks like on affine patches, and verify that the ring homomorphism indeed gives you a finite morphism.

Comment: Closed immersions are finite, but not surjective. Finite coverings are surjective.